# FB.API simple requests failing

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Calling

> FB.Init(InitFinished, "myappid");

Doing a simple login like this:

> FB.Login("user_friends", facebookLogin );

Everything works, get a token back, and i can even use that token successfully in the Graph API Explorer for the same calls

Here's the call from code:

> FB.API ("v2.3/me/friends", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, delegate(FBResult
>   r)...

But in the app, I get this error:

> You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following
>   error when downloading. java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/me

My app has been live for 2 years and aside from occasional FB updates to migrate to newer API versions, nothing's really changed. I added a canvas URL (since it seems to need that now), key hash is correct. What am i missing?

EDIT:

Here's the code around the call:

```
WWWForm frm = new WWWForm();
frm.AddField("fields", "id,picture.width(100),name");
frm.AddField("limit", "50");
FB.API("me", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, delegate(FBResult r) {
    if (r.Error == null) {
         Debug.Log("fb me request came back: "+r.Text);
    } else {
         Debug.Log ("fb me failed with error: " + r.Error);
    }
}, frm);
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use in application?

Comment: Edited the post as i don't think the comments support code formatting

Comment: Hm. Never used `WWWForm` to send API requests. I am usually creating a dictionary for that. The method is `public static void API(string query, HttpMethod method, FacebookDelegate callback = null, Dictionary<string, string> formData = null)`

Comment: guess i didn't look hard enough, saw the WWWForm option, figured it was a way to get in a hash of params... oops :)

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, looks like the problem was passing in a WWWForm to a GET request. I mostly copied the code from a project using prime31 social plugin, and while it takes a hashtable instead of WWWForm, it appears to be smart enough to take the params out and use them as query params on the GET. Would be nice if FB SDK did the same, or at least give a meaningful error...